# Module parse failed: Unexpected token - When using custom NPM module

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I have a Vue 2 project and it shares assets with another, so originally I had them in the same repo and imported them via webpack which worked nicely.  Now I want to import them via NPM using GIT because keeping everything in one repo is no longer practical, and I have sorted the part that imports the module.

So now I have 3 repos: Original, Shared Assets, and Brand New.

Everything works great in the Brand New repo that I am importing them into, but the old project wont build.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (78:32)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| window.makeIdentifier = (payload) => {
>   return "commentOn-" + payload?.sk;
| };
```

So it’s failing to recognise the optional chaining, which seems to be an eslint thing.

To cut a long story short - I've spent far too long trying out various things with eslint now and have started to lose my mind.  I tried copying over the eslint settings but ran into a dependency issues that I could barely read let alone interpret.  I feel defeated by eslint.

(How does anyone stay on top of all these eslint config changes without having these issues?)

Do I need to modify the Original or the Shared repo?
Why would it see optional chaining as an issue in this Shared repo but not in the Original where it's used loads?

Comment: It could be as simple as a version issue.

Comment: Thanks! What version of which part do you have in mind?

Comment: Apparently eslint needs to be 7.5.0 at least for some new language features like that.

Comment: Also you may need to explicitly tell eslint what language version the target will be.

Answer (score 0):

I probably knew this at the time but just wanted to avoid the pain but here's a note to my past self and anyone hitting this page:

You need to go slowly, and bit by bit.  Don't try copying a whole chunk of the package.json as it just adds noise to the problem.

I started with `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-vue`, bringing those inline with the version that worked.  Then babel and the eslint config.  This then complained about other packages that needed upgrading, so I went back to the working version and vue cli installed the latest that would work for these package, and copied those declarations over the old packgage.json then used a final `npm install`.

Here is my changelog:

```
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.15",
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.15",
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.15",
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.15",
-    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.15",
-    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2",
-    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
+    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
+    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
+    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
+    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
+    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
+    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
```

```
-    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
-    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
+    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
+    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
```

```
     "parserOptions": {
-      "parser": "babel-eslint"
+      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
     },
```